# selecting among multiple sockets that are ready to be read from

Tags: java, io, nonblocking

I am writing a server-client application. I have a server that holds several sockets that I have got from the accept() method of ServerSocket. I want to read from these sockets but I don't necesserally know which socket is ready to be read from. I need some kind of selector that will select one of the sockets that are ready to be read from, so I can read the data it sends.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of [java.nio.channels.Selector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)?  However, as it is quite complicated to use, the wrapper library [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) is usually preferred.

Comment: Yes, Netty is wonderful as merryprankster also suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two options to make it work:

1. Have dedicated thread per accepted socket. This is because the 'regular' socket I/O is blocking. You can not selectively handle multiple sockets using a single thread. And as there is no 'peeking' functionality, you will always take a risk of getting blocked when you invoke `read`. By having a thread per each socket you are interested in reading, blocking reads will not block any other operations (threads).
2. Use NIO. NIO allows for asynchronous I/O operations, and basically exactly what you asked for - a *Selector*.

If you do decide to go NIO-way, I would recommend checking out [MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) and [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty). I've found them much easier to work with than plain NIO. Not only will you get a nicer API to work with, but at least MINA had workarounds for some nasty NIO bugs, too.