# Server/Client stop 1 thread = 1 clients

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Protocol: TCP

I have a server with a SocketServer that accepts clients and puts the socket (returned by `ss.accept()`) in an array.

I have 1 thread that needs to be notified when a socket is ready to be read (client sent data).
This thread will dispatch the request to other threads for processing so what this initial thread does is really simple and fast.

Is it possible?

I really want to avoid 1 thread = 1 client and have 1 thread deal with N clients.

Comment: 1 thread multiple clients causes locks / dead locks / client to wait alot. Are you sure?

Comment: This is only for educative purpose, but who can i do if i have 10k clients ? 1 thread = 1 client won't be ... good ?

Comment: most server side solution use connection/ thread pooling to fix that issue.

Comment: @MarkBakker can you explain ? i'm searching but I can't understand how a pool of thread (eg : 5 ) can wait on an array of 10k sockets ? Thanks

Comment: @MarkBakker, I was going to go into more detail, but I take it by the down vote that you were upset with my answer, even though your comment came in when I was writing it. In order to provide quality info to the OP, can you provide your own answer, and include a discussion on conditional variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want to look at the non-blocking IO aspects of [Java NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/) some of which are discussed in this article about the ["Architecture of a Highly Scalable NIO-Based Server"](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/13/architecture-of-highly-scalable-nio-server.html)
Additionally I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097745/selecting-among-multiple-sockets-that-are-ready-to-be-read-from) will help you.

Typically non-blocking IO makes use of callbacks - your code will be required to register a handler to be "called-back" when the data becomes available. In this case the handler would post a message or data to your single thread - which will have to be threadsafe to handle concurrent notifications/callbacks.