# How to do with asyn sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous

I have a big problem, I don't know if it's possible but i'm looking for a tutorial or a similiar post to help me with asyn sockets.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean non-blocking NIO or asynchronous IO in NIO2 (Java 7)? BTW In the tests I did of NIO 2 I found it much more complicated to use and slower unless you have infiniband.

Comment: As non-blocking NIO has been around for ten years there are alot of tutorials on this topic. (Actually google only find 108K, I expected more ;) IMHO using blocking NIO is much simpler and can perform better (for less than 1000 connections)

Comment: Ok thanks ! max connections is 50 so i will try with blocking NIO.

Comment: Blocking NIO, This avoids the need to use selectors. Create one thread per reader, and optionally one thread per writer. BTW blocking NIO is the default for Sockets. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look [here (my post and use the answer of : munyemgm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628420/server-client-stop-1-thread-1-clients)

Java.nio is the solution.

Comment: Thanks Kinaesthesia, I keep this post to use non blocking NIO later.